# Cassandra with groovy test in Jmeter errors

Tags: groovy, cassandra, jmeter

I am setting Jmeter with Groovy of Cassandra DB.
However, I cannot fix these errors.

could you help me?

> Response message: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilatiON-ERRORsException:
>   startup failed: General error during class generation:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Session due to missing dependency
>   org/apache/cassandra/transport/Message$Request

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

1. [Cassandra JDBC Driver itself](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.6.0)
2. All its dependencies, to wit:

   ```
   asm-5.0.3.jar
   asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
   asm-commons-5.0.3.jar
   asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
   asm-util-5.0.3.jar
   guava-19.0.jar
   jffi-1.2.16.jar
   jffi-1.2.16-native.jar
   jnr-constants-0.9.9.jar
   jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar
   jnr-posix-3.0.44.jar
   jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
   metrics-core-3.2.2.jar
   netty-buffer-4.0.56.Final.jar
   netty-codec-4.0.56.Final.jar
   netty-common-4.0.56.Final.jar
   netty-handler-4.0.56.Final.jar
   netty-transport-4.0.56.Final.jar
   slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
   ```

   to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

So you will need to:

- Download `cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar`
- Download all the aforementioned dependencies
- Copy the driver and the dependencies to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
- Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up

More information: [Cassandra Load Testing with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cassandra-load-testing-with-groovy)